# Don't append if string already contains OnChange

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have a javascript OnChange function on a column having textboxes which captures the name of each row in a column. I am appending all the names and storing in variable.
Now , suppose user clicks same textbox again , I don't want to append that name again.

```js
var AppendedString = null;

function onChangeTest(textbox) {
  AppendedString = AppendedString;
  AppendedString = AppendedString + ';' + textbox.name;
  // this gives null;txt_2_4;txt_2_6;txt_3_4;txt_2_4 and so on..and I don't want to append same name again , here it's txt_2_4

}
```

My Input text :

```html
<input type="text" name="txt_<%=l_profileid %>_<%=l_processstepsequence%>" value="<%= l_comments%>" onfocus="this.oldvalue = this.value;" onchange="onChangeTest(this);this.oldvalue = this.value;">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var arr = [];
$("input[type='text']").on("click", function() {
  var nowS = ($(this).attr('name'));
  if (!(arr.indexOf(nowS) > -1)) {
    arr.push(nowS)
  }
  console.log(arr)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="m1" name="lbl1">
<input type="text" id="m2" name="lbl2">
<input type="text" id="m3" name="lbl3">
```

Somewhat similar to your need,

```js
var arr = [];
$("input[type='text']").on("click", function() {
  var nowS = ($(this).attr('name'));
  if (!arr.includes(nowS)) {
    arr.push(nowS)
  }
  console.log(arr)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="m1" name="lbl1">
<input type="text" id="m2" name="lbl2">
<input type="text" id="m3" name="lbl3">
```

Comment: to run and check code in webpage I need to write alert instead of console.log right?

Comment: Yes it's working on Chrome but I need something similar for IE. Is there any hack?. Thank you for helping me out.

Comment: I add little change in code it would work on both chrome and IE too

Comment: I am not able to upvote but I have marked it as answer. Can I split the output ? I am getting txt_2_4 so I want to pick 2 and 4 and store it in a variable.

Comment: yes you can but you have to maintain same name with number.like lbl1,lbl2 .By using                                                                                                                  var m="lbl1";
console.log(m.slice(3))

Answer (score 1):

Those rows seem to have unique names.
you can simply check if AppendedString already contains that name :

```
var AppendedString=''

function onChangeTest(textbox) {
  if (!AppendedString.includes(textbox.name)) {
    AppendedString += ';' + textbox.name;
  }
}
```

[Codepen Link](https://codepen.io/anisometropie/pen/zeJWwO)

You can’t initialize `AppendedString` as `null` otherwise, the `includes()` method won’t be available

otherwise, you can give each row a unique ID, and store in an array IDs that already have been clicked by the user.

```
var AppendedString = '';
var clickedRows = [];

function onChangeTest(textbox) {
      if (!clickedRows.includes(textbox.id)) {
        AppendedString += ';' + textbox.name;
        clickedRows.push(textbox.id)
      }
    }
```

Comment: Yes rows are unique. I tried your code and it is not doing anything. Even, to test, alert is not getting fired.

Comment: Did you initialize AppendedString as an empty string ?

Comment: Yes I did and it shows blank alert , with null it was showing null in the alert. it means it's not appending antyhing.

Comment: There was a mistake in my answer, I was checking for `includes(textbox)`. instead of `includes(textbox.name)`

Comment: May be I am doing something wrong. When I run your code without if statement and I check with alert then after every click on text boxes I am getting all the names but when I apply if statement then alert doesnt fire after every textbox click

Comment: I need to see what you’re doing, can you make a codepen ?

Comment: Yes it's working on Chrome ( or may be in another modern browsers too) but I am using IE. Is there any way to perform something similar for IE?

Answer (score 0):

You can add flag your textboxes and ignore if it's clicked again. Like using jquery you can do something like this:

```
function onChangeTest(textbox) {
    AppendedString = AppendedString;
    if (!textbox.hasClass("clicked")){
        AppendedString = AppendedString + ';' + textbox.name;
        textbox.AddClass("clicked");
    }
 }
```

Comment: I need to use javascript only.